# how to use rasa as library to train model and for testing

Tags: python, deep-learning, nlp, rasa

I want to use rasa as library instead of framework and using resa as library I want to train model as we train in framework using config,nlu and stories.

Answer (score 0):

```
import rasa

config = 'confing.yml'
training_files = './data/'
domain = 'domain.yml'
output = './models/'

rasa.train(domain, config, [training_files], output, fixed_model_name='model_name')
```

thanks to : [How to reduce model loading time in rasa 3 python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73377097/how-to-reduce-model-loading-time-in-rasa-3-python)